# node.js express.static doesn't work properly

Tags: node.js, express

I have a project folder of the following structure:

> Main Directory
>
> - 'client' directory: includes html, css and js files.
> - 'img' directory: includes images
> - server directory

Inside server directory I have a node.js file:

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../img/')) );
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/')) );


app.get('/', function(req,res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client/index.html'));
});
```

The index.html file "calls" css and js files that exist in 'client' directory and it also "calls" images that exist in 'img' directory.

However, when I open my browser and send a GET request a see an html page that can't read the images. I guess that something is wrong with

```
app.use('/', express.static(...));
```

but I don't know what. Can anyone help me figure out?

Comment: I don't know why the images are not coming. But you can try two things. 1. To change one path to something else like "/img" or "/client". 2. or move your img folder in your client folder and only make client folder static. You can read more [here](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

Comment: Try changing the order of your static directories: `app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/')) ); app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../img/')) );`. What's the path you are using in your HTML for images?

Comment: in my html the path for images is: 
<img src="../img/logo.png">.
I also tried to switch order. It didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Well... it seems that I've figured it out by myself.

Although the images are not in the same directory as html.index, the moment I use express.static, the content of the "imported" library is "brought" to the same directory of the node.js file.

Therefore, inside the html file, instead of writing:

```
<img src="../img/logo.png" id="logo">
```

I wrote:

```
<img src="logo.png" id="logo">
```

and it worked.

Comment: It's not imported, you used static to map the two directories both to the root (/) path.  This is probably OK in this case since one has images and the other presumably not, but if you have in the future files in both directories with the same name you might get unexpected behavior.

Comment: so in these cases what would you advise me to do to avoid such unexpected behavior?

Comment: Most folks have a single folder that all static files will be in (e.g. public) and then pit sub folders in there by type (e.g. ./public/js, ./public/img).  Those sub folders will all be available as relative to the mapped folders so you would then set the path to them as /img/pic1.png and so on.  Alternatively if you want multiple source folders, mount them on different paths